# Constant line spacing with variable item size in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a UICollectionView with horizontal scroll and variable sized items.

[image: Screenshot]

Is it possible to have constant spacing between items in 'horizontal' rows?

[image: screenshot2]

Thanks.

Comment: looks to me like your cells are all the same size, just the size of the labels is varied. you should post your cell creation code - what are you sending for sizeForItem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide cell's variable width. Implement this method from **UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let size = (items[indexPath.item] as NSString).size(attributes: nil)
    return CGSize(width: size.width + yourTextPadding, height: yourCellHeight)
}
```

You can also provide label's font attributes for exact computation or just use some constant (like 2 times width of text).